# Google script - Create initial value based on other column if not blank

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have database in Google Sheets, Let's say the named sheet is Micro FG. In Sheet Micro FG consist of 20 columns, in the range `Micro FG!A:T` as link of sample sheet below:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nI3DdBCtZWfpQ2FQfAsNOmpqVN5jRxjKOU77-YCJQTI/edit?usp=sharing
```

In column J, K, L, M, and N, I would like to create initial value automatically based on column A if not empty. Column A is containing formula who can call from another sheet (the name sheet is Micro FG Temp).

Before that i have created app script and it worked. Following my script below:

```
function setInitialValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Micro FG");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataToSet = [];

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cellA = sheet.getRange("A" + i);
    var cellJ = sheet.getRange("J" + i);

    if (cellA.getValue() != "" && cellJ.getValue() == "") {
      dataToSet.push(["Initial Value 10", "Initial Value 11", "Initial Value 12", "Initial Value 13", "Initial Value 14"]);
    } else if (cellA.getValue() == "" && cellJ.getValue() != "") {
      dataToSet.push(["", "", "", "", ""]);
    }
  }

  if (dataToSet.length > 0) {
    var rangeToSet = sheet.getRange(2, 10, dataToSet.length, 5);
    rangeToSet.setValues(dataToSet);
  }
}

function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var sheet = editedRange.getSheet();
  var column = editedRange.getColumn();
  var row = editedRange.getRow();
  
  if (column == 1 && row > 1) {
    setInitialValues();
  }
}
```

But i have other problem if column J, K, L, M, and N, if I deleted or edit, the initial value appearing again. My goal is I would like to column J, K, L, M, and N can editable or delete if the corresponding cell in column A is still not empty.

Please advise me how I can fix the script to correct this sheet especially for column J, K, L, M, and N. Thankyou

Comment: If `setInitialValues` is run with `onEditTrigger` of the OnEdit trigger, I think that `setInitialValues` is run when column "A" is edited. But, you say `But i have other problem if column J, K, L, M, and N, I deleted or edit, the initial value appearing again.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script in your question. How about this?

Comment: Sorry, in column J, K, L, M, and N, if i edit or delete the initial value appearing again (the condition if i did not delete column A).

Comment: is there wrong in my code sir?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `in column J, K, L, M, and N, if i edit or delete the initial value appearing again (the condition if i did not delete column A).`. Can I ask you about the details of it? About my 1st comment, can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: i mean if column J until N has set a initial value, then if i delete or edit manually, the initial value still appearing again even column A is still not empty.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `i mean if column J until N has set a initial value, then if i delete or edit manually, the initial value still appearing again even column A is still not empty.`, in the case of your showing script, I think that when the columns "J" to "N" are deleted, the values of columns "J" to "N" are kept to delete. So, I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result?